# How to play audio in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I have below code in JS to play audio

```
playThis = Audio + '/Audios/Orchestral/Organic_cloudcity.mp3'

    playAudio() {
        let audio = new Audio();
        audio.src = this.playThis;
        audio.load();
        audio.play();
    }

connectedcallback() {

        this.playAudio();
}
```

this doesn't work on chrome browser because of its auto play policy can anyone suggest if is there any work around to  auto play this in chrome browser?

even this  [trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/add-sound-effects-to-your-sf-org) adding sound effects in lwc doesn't  work in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Auto play is a browser feature. If the autoplay is off, there is unlikely you will be able to do anything. This is a user setting and triumph over whatever code you will write.

These changes have been around in Chrome since 2017

Autoplay with sound is allowed if:

- User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
- On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously played video with sound.
- The user has added the site to their home screen on mobile or installed the PWA on desktop.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes